# Rasa emojis prevent command from being run

Tags: python, unicode, rasa, rasa-x

I have been trying to follow the installation of rasa at the top of [this page](http://pip%20install%20rasa-x%20--extra-index-url%20https://pypi.rasa.com/simple). 
The first installation command returns fine:
`pip install rasa-x --extra-index-url https://pypi.rasa.com/simple`
but when i run `rasa init`, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Uzay\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\rasa.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\__main__.py", line 76, in main
    cmdline_arguments.func(cmdline_arguments)
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\scaffold.py", line 159, in run
    print_success("Welcome to Rasa! \U0001f916\n")
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\utils.py", line 147, in print_success
    print_color(*args, color=bcolors.OKGREEN)
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\rasa\cli\utils.py", line 143, in print_color
    print (wrap_with_color(*args, color=color))
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 187, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, start)
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 195, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 41, in write
    self.__convertor.write(text)
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 162, in write
    self.write_and_convert(text)
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 190, in write_and_convert
    self.write_plain_text(text, cursor, len(text))
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\colorama\ansitowin32.py", line 195, in write_plain_text
    self.wrapped.write(text[start:end])
  File "c:\users\uzay\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f916' in position 17: character maps to <undefined>
```

I've been looking at the rasa file that is creating this problem which is named scaffold.py and it contains many emojis including this line that throws the error:
`print_success("Welcome to Rasa! \U0001f916 \n")`

The long `\U0001f916` is the encoding of an emoji of which there are many in the scaffold file.
I have tried commenting out the line and removing the emoji but the error still remains. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Could you confirm if running `chcp 65001` (as described here) before you run the command fixes it?

Comment: @msamogh Thank you so much that fixed it. What does that do?